# httr::content throws error when supplying a variable as the request object

Tags: r, jira, jira-rest-api, httr

I am trying to get a list of Jira tickets that were opened from anyone within an organization. I have a list of user IDs but there are nearly 1400 people in this organization.

Since there are this many folks I cannot simply query all of them in 1 request so I created a loop to do so. The GET request part of the loop works fine and I get a response back for each ID (whether or not any Jira tickets were actually created by that user). Where I run into an issue is trying to extract the content of these responses, httr::content throws the error `is.response(x) is not true` . This seems to be due to me passing the list as x to 'content' though I have tried some other options as well with no success.

```
org_list <- as.data.frame(read.csv("org_list.csv"))
```

Where the csv file is like this (but with 1378 IDs):

```
ID 
abc123 
xyz987
```

Here is the loop:

```
for (i in 1:1378) {

assign(paste0("query_", org_list[i,]), GET("https://myjira.com/", 
                   path = "rest/api/2/search", 
                   query = list(jql = paste0("project in (ABC,DEF,XYZ) AND reporter = ", org_list[i,]), maxResults = 500),
                   authenticate(my_UN, my_PW),
                   verbose()
) 
)

  tmp_var <-  as.character(org_list[i,])
  api_request_content <- httr::content(tmp_var, as = "text")
  api_request_content_flat <- fromJSON(api_request_content, flatten = TRUE)
  assign(paste0("data_", tmp_var), as.data.frame(api_request_content_flat$issues))
  rm(paste0("query_", tmp_var))

}
```

This creates a response object like "query_abc123", "query_xyz987", etc. The loop itself works fine if I remove everything outside of 'assign' function.

I have also tried:

```
api_request_content <- httr::content(org_list[i,], as = "text")
```

And

```
api_request_content <- httr::content(paste0(org_list[i,]), as = "text")
```

And they all return the same error. 
But if I manually pass the object like

```
api_request_content <- httr::content(query_abc123, as = "text")
```

Everything works as intended. An afternoon of Googling hasn't returned anything even close to an answer for me on this.

Comment: Don't use `as.character` on `org_list[i,]`. The `context()` function expect an httr response object, not a character value. Try just `httr::content(org_list[i,], as = "text")`

Comment: Actually, wait, what's with the use of assign() here. That seems to be messing things up because you are creating crazy variable names. Are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: @MrFlick, I already tried your suggestion as you can see towards the bottom of the post

Comment: @MrFlick in the end I want a single report of these issues. Assign creates an object like "query_abc123", "query_xyz987", etc. which should then get flattened out to "data_"query_abc123", and "data_query_xyz987", etc.. After this loop runs I intend to use dplyr::bind_rows to build a single dataframe with all of the data

Comment: Then you should just use an `lapply` to do the loop and create a list. If you save the result from the `GET()` to a variable, like `tmp <- GET(...)`, then you can get the content with `httr::content(tmp, as = "text")`. I strongly encourage you to avoid `assign()` and it's counter part lowercase `get()`. That's really where your problems are coming from here.

Comment: @MrFlick would you mind posting an answer with more details? I don't use the different apply functions much other than dplyr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a proper reproducible example, this is all kind of guess work, but a more common strategy would be something like this

```
alldata <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(as.character(org_list[[1]]), function(reporter) {

  req <- GET("https://myjira.com/", 
            path = "rest/api/2/search", 
            query = list(jql = paste0("project in (ABC,DEF,XYZ) AND reporter = ", reporter), maxResults = 500),
            authenticate(my_UN, my_PW),
            verbose()
  ) 

  api_request_content <- httr::content(req, as = "text")
  api_request_content_flat <- fromJSON(api_request_content, flatten = TRUE)
  as.data.frame(api_request_content_flat$issues)
}))
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Comment: What if I wanted to add back the ID column to this? I tried adding the following to the end after as.data.frame... : dplyr::mutate(api_request_content_flat, "Reporter" = reporter). But I get this: no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "list". I thought mutate would play nice with bind_rows but sending it the list doesn't seem to have the effect I was expecting.

Comment: Did you try `as.data.frame(api_request_content_flat$issues) %>% mutate(Reporter=reporter)`? You need to pass in the data.frame, not the the flattened list.

Comment: whelp, I tried like this: 
api_request_content_flat <- as.data.frame(api_request_content_flat); mutate(api_request_content_flat, Reporter = reporter) and that didn't work. But I just tossed in what you gave me and it worked! I am glad but confused...